# Multiple output with same session_id

Tags: sql-server, ssms

```
DECLARE @mgcounter INT
SET @mgcounter = 1

WHILE @mgcounter = 1
BEGIN 
    IF (SELECT COUNT (*)
        FROM sys.dm_exec_query_memory_grants) >  0
    BEGIN
        SELECT * 
        FROM sys.dm_exec_query_memory_grants mg
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(mg.sql_handle)     
    END
END
```

I used the code above to monitor the memory usage of queries executing in our server. My problem is it will end up to output multiple query with the same session_id and details. What I want to do is to display multiple query with different session id and details.

Please run the code to understand what am I saying.

Comment: To explain this in more detail, would you add to this question: (1) a sample of the output now, and (2) a sample of the output you want?

Answer (score 0):

please use cursor instead of while loop.